# custom tokenizer not generating tokens as expected if text contains special characters like # , @

Tags: elasticsearch, token, tokenize, analyzer

**i have defined the following tokenizer :**

```
PUT /testanlyzer2
{
        "settings" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "nGram",
                        "min_gram" : "1",
                        "max_gram" : "3",
                        "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit","symbol","currency_symbol","modifier_symbol","other_symbol" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

For the following request 
  GET /testanlyzer2/_analyze?analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer&text="i a#m not available 9177"

Result is:

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "i",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 3,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

**For the following request::**

```
GET /testanlyzer2/_analyze?analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer&text="i a#m not available 9177"
```

**Result is::**

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "i",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 3,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

**For the following request ::**

```
GET /testanlyzer2/_analyze?analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer&text="i a@m not available 9177"
```

**Result is :**

```
Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):

Expected result should contain these special characters(@,#,currency's,etc..) as tokens. please correct me if anything wrong in my custom tokenizer.
```

--Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is a special character in Sense (if you are using the Marvel's Sense dashboard) and it comments out the line.

To remove any html escaping/Sense special chars, I would test this like this:

```
PUT /testanlyzer2
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "substring"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /testanlyzer2/test/1
{
  "text": "i a@m not available 9177"
}

POST /testanlyzer2/test/2
{
  "text": "i a#m not available 9177"
}

GET /testanlyzer2/test/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["text"]
}
```

Comment: ..thanks its working but i have one more problem with dollar . could you look at my recent post.